# Best Practice for fill dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a question. I fill dropdownlist models in a view model and send them to a view. This is better method rather than using `ViewBag`.

But when view model is sent to the `Controller`, this extra data will be sent to the `Controller`. Now if I use bind attribute for receiving some properties and `ModelState` is invalid, I should fill them and send to view again?? What is the best practice in these cases?

Comment: The best is of course you create a view model and put the select list in as it is strongly typed rather than using a viewbag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewBag` that will help you to avoid such kind of validation.

e.g. you have country data as a dropdown you can bind it to ViewBag and set it in Dropdown and for rest of the part you can supplied your own model which is required to supplied in view.

following is an example with ViewBag and Model.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Home()
   {
    your Model
     ABCModel model = new ABCModel();
     // your ViewBag
     ViewBag.Country = new SelectList(db.Contries.ToList(),"Id","Name");
     return View(model)
   }
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Home(ABCModel model)
   {
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        // your action
     }
     return View(model);// you can redirect to other page as per your requirements
   }
 }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model ABCModel // define your required model
```

bind dropdown like below

```
@Html.DropDownList("Country",ViewBag.Country as SelectList)
```

Comment: thank you. but this comment is not related to my question. my question is that if we import extra models in viewmodel in every callback to server we must send extra data and is a alternate method or not.

Comment: Yes whatever in model you supplied those data will be send with the request.

Comment: you don't understand my purpose. i know that in every callback to controller all of model properties will bet sent but my purpose is that if you have 10 select in your view and your model have errors and you send models 10 times to controller, in fact you sent heavy data 10 times and it have overhead and traffic bandwidth.